# PhantomJS does not exist Error

Tags: phantomjs, cloudboost

I get error `PhantomJS does not exist at '/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs` on the terminal upon running the tests (npm tests) for Cloudboost Javascript SDK repo. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install PhantomJS from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), and create a symlink of the downloaded folder in your `/usr/local/` directory. Run the command `npm test` again and that error would be gone.